# Searching for function usage in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have inherited an Excel spreadsheet with many VBA functions and it's not clear where (or even if) a lot of them are being used.

Is there a way to find the usage of a VBA function, or perhaps search for invocations of it, similar to the way you can click on a function/method in a standard IDE and find its usage throughout the codebase?  I am looking for the **cells** from which the functions could be being called, not invocations from within other VBA functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In VBA** - Use CTRL+F and select "Current Project" to find each usage of the function name in the project.

**On Worksheet** - Use CTRL+F and make sure "Look In" is set to "Formulas." Then click "Find All" to find each usage of the function name in the worksheet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say that I was looking for cells on the sheet where the function may be called, not from within other VBA functions.  I'll edit question appropriately - thx.

Comment: You can use the `Find` method on the sheet to look for function names as well. Just make sure that "Look in:" is set to "Formulas". You can then click "Find All" to see all instances where the function is used.